# What does GLaDOS mean with "One day they woke me up"?

Tags: portal-2

A few days back I completed Portal and Portal 2. I had a lot of questions about this awesome game, like who Caroline is, why there's no personnel and other things that I didn't understand.

I am interested in the start of story. There was a line in the ending song Want You Gone:

```
One day they woke me up
```

What does this mean? Who woke her up or does this line have another meaning?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They mean the day she was initialized. During the game Cave Johnson mentions that he wants his team to take the personality of Caroline and put her in a computer.

Since GLaDOS exists, we must assume that his team succeeded in doing this. So they started building her and putting Caroline's personality into GLaDOS. Then, one day they woke her up so she could live forever and feel bad for Chell because it'll never happen to her.

Comment: Ratman comics actually picture that day.

Answer (score 11):

This started when Cave got his disease from moon dust. He wanted to live longer, so he asked his engineers to build something that he could transfer his mind into. He also ordered that if he passed away before the machine was completed, Caroline would be transferred instead. Since he does, indeed die before it was built, Caroline was forced to be transferred into the machine.

A long time later, GLaDOS(Caroline) was activated. And that's why she says that line.

Also, there are some disturbing lines from the game which were cut telling how Caroline was transferred, only a few of these lines are found in the game files.

The disturbing part starts at 0:28. Hope my post helps.

Comment: That's... creepy O_O

Answer (score 2):

Caroline was the assistant of Cave Johnson. He had Caroline's mind put into the computer. When they turned her on she flooded the complex with a deadly nerve toxin. That is why there is no personnel and that is what the song means by one day they woke me up.

Answer (score -1):

If you have played through the original Portal, at the end (spoilers if you haven't played it and want to) she is destroyed but "still alive" (hence the end song still alive). In Portal 2, when you and Wheatley go through "her chamber" and are looking for escape pod you start turning on switches as you move up the tube, essentially "waking her up". That could be it, or just the fact that caroline is GLaDOS (found out after you get potados).

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is that she refers to the scientists who built her, Wheatley who revived her, and most importantly, Caroline, who woke up GLaDOS's loving and humanly characteristics, especially to Chell, seeing as basically EVRYTHING about Caroline and Cave seem to point to Chell being their daughter.

Comment: Is there a source for the Cave/Caroline as Chell's parents part?